Blazor MAUI Arch Linux - Maui Check ask for emulator 31
I'm trying to install on my arch linux the MAUI android but I have an issue when I run the maui-check command
It look that an emulator is missing :
⏳ Synchronizing configuration... ok
⏳ Scheduling appointments... ok

 OpenJDK 11.0 Checkup...
  ✔ 22.0.2 (/usr/lib/jvm/java-22-openjdk/bin/..)

 Android SDK Checkup...
  ❌ emulator (31.3.12) missing.
  ✔ build-tools;33.0.0 (33.0.0)
  ✔ platforms;android-33 (3)
  ✔ system-images;android-33;google_apis;x86_64 (16)
  ✔ platform-tools (35.0.2)
  ✔ cmdline-tools;8.0 (8.0)

Of course, I installed some emulator with android 31 - 33 & 35 but I still have the error.
The only thing that I found about emulator in the Android SDK Manager is this one :

And the version is 35... Someone can told me if I'm wrong and If any solution exist.
Thanks

Firstly, could you create a maui project and run it for android platform in the arch linux? If yes, no need to use MAUI check tools to validate it. If no, please check this baronfel's reply , using the dotnet-install scripts to install a 'local install' of the Microsoft SDK and use that.
